# Ajax with wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm make an ajax call to run a file:

```
var data = 'index=exp' + index;
var go_url = get_bloginfo('template_url') + '/form/exp.php';
$.ajax({
   url: go_url, 
   type: "GET",     
   data: data,      
   cache: false
});
```

The file "exp.php" inserts a new row in mysql database and it works.. but with the ajax call nothing happens. As if he did not open the link.

Comment: Does your php file return any values back to the browser?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add 'add_action' for functions in wordpress
like

`function yourfunction(){
...
}
add_action('wp_ajax_your_function', 'yourfunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_function', 'yourfunction');`

and in your jquery you can call 'your_function' instead of php file

Answer (score 0):

Is the ajax being called?

Try putting it inside of document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

Comment: I realized that is the "go_url" that is not working and does not call the file .. but I do not understand why.